# Connection problem of ESP8266 ESP-01 arduino uno to cayenne

Tags: arduino, wifi, mqtt, iot, arduino-uno

I am using the ESP8266 Wi-Fi shield to connect Arduino to the cayenne server. However once connect the chip to the access point it will heat up and sometimes will lagging. After that, it shows some message but the Cayenne server didn't connect to the Arduino. Every widget can not be operated (No response when clicking a button, temperature value unchanged, etc.). Can anyone solve this issue? It is important for my course work. I am using Arduino Uno and ESP8266 ESP-01 chip. We have tried different styles of code to upload data to cayenne server but they didn't work(Below include 3 versions)

Finale 1 Version(Cayenne out) :

```
#define CAYENNE_PRINT Serial
#include <CayenneMQTTESP8266Shield.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <virtuabotixRTC.h>

//Real+Virtual
#define LED_PIN 5
#define temp_sensor 4
#define EspSerial Serial

//Virtual
#define Power_sensor 9
#define DayPower 10
#define MonthPower 11
#define LED_PWM 12

//SSID

char ssid[] = "TP-LINK_MWNg";
char password[] = "mwngpass";

char username[] = "743674368676328742somenumbers";
char mqtt_password[] = "743674368676328742somenumbers";
char client_id[] = "743674368676328742somenumbers";

ESP8266 wifi(&EspSerial);

//Temperature setup
OneWire oneWire(4);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

//Power sensor
const int analogInPin = A0;
int sensorValue = 0;        // value read from the pot
float MAXValue = 0;        // value output to the PWM (analog out)
float Power = 0;
int PWM = 0;

//Time
int curSec = 0;
int curMin = 0;
int curHour = 0;
int curDay = 0;
virtuabotixRTC myRTC(6, 7, 8);
unsigned PowerInDay = 0;
unsigned PowerInMonth = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  sensors.begin();
  EspSerial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Cayenne.begin(username, mqtt_password, client_id, wifi, ssid, password);

  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(LED_PIN, PWM);

  curSec = myRTC.seconds;
  curMin = myRTC.minutes;
  curHour = myRTC.hours;
  curDay = myRTC.dayofmonth;

  //test

}

void loop() {
  Cayenne.loop();
  myRTC.updateTime();
  if ( curSec != myRTC.seconds ) {
    PowerInDay += Power;
    curSec = myRTC.seconds;
  }
  if (curDay != myRTC.dayofmonth) {
    PowerInMonth += PowerInDay;
    PowerInDay = 0;
    curDay = myRTC.dayofmonth;
  }
  if (curDay > myRTC.dayofmonth) {
    PowerInMonth = 0;
  }
  Serial.print(myRTC.dayofmonth);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(myRTC.month);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(myRTC.year);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(myRTC.hours);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(myRTC.minutes);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(myRTC.seconds);
  Serial.print('\n');
  Serial.print(PowerInDay);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(PowerInMonth);
  Serial.print('\n');

}

CAYENNE_OUT(temp_sensor)
{
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  Cayenne.celsiusWrite(temp_sensor, sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
}

CAYENNE_OUT(Power_sensor)
{
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
  // map it to the range of the analog out:
  if (sensorValue > 0)
    MAXValue = sensorValue * 0.00007307;

  Power = MAXValue * ((float)PWM / (float)255) * 3.3 * ((float)PWM / (float)255);
  // change the analog out value:/

  // print the results to the serial monitor:
  Serial.print("sensor = ");
  Serial.print(sensorValue); //RAW value from analog read :)
  Serial.print("\t output = ");
  Serial.println(MAXValue * ((float)PWM / (float)255), 3); //Output the current
  Serial.print("Power =");
  Serial.println(Power, 3);
  // wait 2 milliseconds before the next loop
  // for the analog-to-digital converter to settle
  // after the last reading:
  delay(50);
  Cayenne.virtualWrite(Power_sensor, Power, "pow", "w");
}

CAYENNE_OUT(DayPower) {
  Cayenne.virtualWrite(DayPower, PowerInDay, "pow", "w");
}

CAYENNE_OUT(MonthPower) {
  Cayenne.virtualWrite(MonthPower, PowerInMonth, "pow", "w");
}


CAYENNE_IN(LED_PIN)
{
  int currentValue = getValue.asInt();
  if (currentValue == 1) {
    PWM = 255;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
  } else {
    PWM = 0;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  }
  //digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
  //Process message here. If there is an error set an error message using getValue.setError(), e.g getValue.setError("Error message");
}

CAYENNE_IN(LED_PWM)
{
  int value = getValue.asInt(); // 0 to 255
  PWM = value;
  analogWrite(LED_PIN, value);
}
```

Finale 2 Version(Cayenne out_Default):

```
#define CAYENNE_PRINT Serial
#include <CayenneMQTTESP8266Shield.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <virtuabotixRTC.h>

//Real+Virtual
#define LED_PIN 5
#define temp_sensor 4
#define EspSerial Serial

//Virtual
#define Power_sensor 9
#define DayPower 10
#define MonthPower 11
#define LED_PWM 12

//SSID

char ssid[] = "TP-LINK_MWNg";
char password[] = "mwngpass";

char username[] = "743674368676328742somenumbers";
char mqtt_password[] = "743674368676328742somenumbers";
char client_id[] = "743674368676328742somenumbers";

ESP8266 wifi(&EspSerial);

//Temperature setup
OneWire oneWire(4);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

//Power sensor
const int analogInPin = A0;
int sensorValue = 0;        // value read from the pot
float MAXValue = 0;        // value output to the PWM (analog out)
float Power = 0;
int PWM = 0;

//Time
int curSec = 0;
int curMin = 0;
int curHour = 0;
int curDay = 0;
virtuabotixRTC myRTC(6, 7, 8);
unsigned PowerInDay = 0;
unsigned PowerInMonth = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  sensors.begin();
  EspSerial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Cayenne.begin(username, mqtt_password, client_id, wifi, ssid, password);

  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(LED_PIN, PWM);

  curSec = myRTC.seconds;
  curMin = myRTC.minutes;
  curHour = myRTC.hours;
  curDay = myRTC.dayofmonth;

  //test

}

void loop() {
  Cayenne.loop();
  myRTC.updateTime();
  if ( curSec != myRTC.seconds ) {
    PowerInDay += Power;
    curSec = myRTC.seconds;
  }
  if (curDay != myRTC.dayofmonth) {
    PowerInMonth += PowerInDay;
    PowerInDay = 0;
    curDay = myRTC.dayofmonth;
  }
  if (curDay > myRTC.dayofmonth) {
    PowerInMonth = 0;
  }
  Serial.print(myRTC.dayofmonth);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(myRTC.month);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(myRTC.year);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(myRTC.hours);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(myRTC.minutes);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(myRTC.seconds);
  Serial.print('\n');
  Serial.print(PowerInDay);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(PowerInMonth);
  Serial.print('\n');

}

  CAYENNE_OUT_DEFAULT()
  {
  //Temp sensor-----------------------------------------
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  Cayenne.celsiusWrite(temp_sensor, sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
  //Temp sensor-----------------------------------------

  //Power sensor-------------------------------------------------
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
  // map it to the range of the analog out:
  if (sensorValue > 0)
    MAXValue = sensorValue * 0.00007307;

  Power = MAXValue * ((float)PWM / (float)255) * 3.3 * ((float)PWM / (float)255);
  // change the analog out value:/

  // print the results to the serial monitor:
  Serial.print("sensor = ");
  Serial.print(sensorValue); //RAW value from analog read :)
  Serial.print("\t output = ");
  Serial.println(MAXValue * ((float)PWM / (float)255), 3); //Output the current
  Serial.print("Power =");
  Serial.println(Power, 3);
  // wait 2 milliseconds before the next loop
  // for the analog-to-digital converter to settle
  // after the last reading:
  delay(50);
  Cayenne.virtualWrite(Power_sensor, Power, "pow", "w");
  //Power sensor-------------------------------------------------

  //Power Day-------------------------------------------------
  Cayenne.virtualWrite(DayPower, PowerInDay, "pow", "w");

  //Power Month-------------------------------------------------
  Cayenne.virtualWrite(MonthPower, PowerInMonth, "pow", "w");

  }

CAYENNE_IN(LED_PIN)
{
  int currentValue = getValue.asInt();
  if (currentValue == 1) {
    PWM = 255;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
  } else {
    PWM = 0;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  }
  //digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
  //Process message here. If there is an error set an error message using getValue.setError(), e.g getValue.setError("Error message");
}

CAYENNE_IN(LED_PWM)
{
  int value = getValue.asInt(); // 0 to 255
  PWM = value;
  analogWrite(LED_PIN, value);
}
```

Finale 3 Version(Send data with time difference):

```
#define CAYENNE_PRINT Serial
#include <CayenneMQTTESP8266Shield.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <virtuabotixRTC.h>

//Real+Virtual
#define LED_PIN 5
#define temp_sensor 4
#define EspSerial Serial

//Virtual
#define Power_sensor 9
#define DayPower 10
#define MonthPower 11
#define LED_PWM 12

//SSID

char ssid[] = "TP-LINK_MWNg";
char password[] = "mwngpass";

char username[] = "743674368676328742somenumbers";
char mqtt_password[] = "743674368676328742somenumbers";
char client_id[] = "743674368676328742somenumbers";

ESP8266 wifi(&EspSerial);

//Temperature setup
OneWire oneWire(4);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

//Power sensor
const int analogInPin = A0;
int sensorValue = 0;        // value read from the pot
float MAXValue = 0;        // value output to the PWM (analog out)
float Power = 0;
int PWM = 0;

//Time
int curSec = 0;
int curMin = 0;
int curHour = 0;
int curDay = 0;
virtuabotixRTC myRTC(6, 7, 8);
unsigned PowerInDay = 0;
unsigned PowerInMonth = 0;
int lastMillis = 0;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  sensors.begin();
  EspSerial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Cayenne.begin(username, mqtt_password, client_id, wifi, ssid, password);

  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(LED_PIN, PWM);

  curSec = myRTC.seconds;
  curMin = myRTC.minutes;
  curHour = myRTC.hours;
  curDay = myRTC.dayofmonth;

  //test

}

void loop() {
  Cayenne.loop();
  myRTC.updateTime();
  if ( curSec != myRTC.seconds ) {
    PowerInDay += Power;
    curSec = myRTC.seconds;
  }
  if (curDay != myRTC.dayofmonth) {
    PowerInMonth += PowerInDay;
    PowerInDay = 0;
    curDay = myRTC.dayofmonth;
  }
  if (curDay > myRTC.dayofmonth) {
    PowerInMonth = 0;
  }
//  Serial.print(myRTC.dayofmonth);
//  Serial.print('/');
//  Serial.print(myRTC.month);
//  Serial.print('/');
//  Serial.print(myRTC.year);
//  Serial.print('/');
//  Serial.print(' ');
//  Serial.print(myRTC.hours);
//  Serial.print(':');
//  Serial.print(myRTC.minutes);
//  Serial.print(':');
//  Serial.print(myRTC.seconds);
//  Serial.print('\n');
//  Serial.print(PowerInDay);
//  Serial.print(' ');
//  Serial.print(PowerInMonth);
//  Serial.print('\n');

 if(millis() - lastMillis > 10000 && millis() - lastMillis < 20000 ) {//Send data between 10 - 20 seconds
   //Temp sensor-----------------------------------------
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  Cayenne.celsiusWrite(temp_sensor, sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
  //Temp sensor-----------------------------------------
   }
 if(millis() - lastMillis > 20000 && millis() - lastMillis < 30000 ) {//Send data between 20 - 30 seconds
      //Power sensor-------------------------------------------------
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
  // map it to the range of the analog out:
  if (sensorValue > 0)
    MAXValue = sensorValue * 0.00007307;

  Power = MAXValue * ((float)PWM / (float)255) * 3.3 * ((float)PWM / (float)255);
  // change the analog out value:/

  // print the results to the serial monitor:
  Serial.print("sensor = ");
  Serial.print(sensorValue); //RAW value from analog read :)
  Serial.print("\t output = ");
  Serial.println(MAXValue * ((float)PWM / (float)255), 3); //Output the current
  Serial.print("Power =");
  Serial.println(Power, 3);
  // wait 2 milliseconds before the next loop
  // for the analog-to-digital converter to settle
  // after the last reading:
  delay(50);
  Cayenne.virtualWrite(Power_sensor, Power, "pow", "w");
  //Power sensor-------------------------------------------------

   }
 if(millis() - lastMillis > 30000 && millis() - lastMillis < 40000 ) {//Send data between 30 - 40 seconds

      //Power Day-------------------------------------------------
  Cayenne.virtualWrite(DayPower, PowerInDay, "pow", "w");
   }
 if(millis() - lastMillis > 40000 && millis() - lastMillis < 50000 ) {//Send data between 40 - 50 seconds

       //Power Month-------------------------------------------------
  Cayenne.virtualWrite(MonthPower, PowerInMonth, "pow", "w");
  lastMillis = millis();
   }

}

CAYENNE_IN(LED_PIN)
{
  int currentValue = getValue.asInt();
  if (currentValue == 1) {
    PWM = 255;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
  } else {
    PWM = 0;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  }
  //digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
  //Process message here. If there is an error set an error message using getValue.setError(), e.g getValue.setError("Error message");
}
CAYENNE_IN(LED_PWM)
{
  int value = getValue.asInt(); // 0 to 255
  PWM = value;
  analogWrite(LED_PIN, value);
}
```

Serial monitor message:

```
AT
ATE0
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CWMODE?
AT+CWJAP="TP-LINK_MWNg","mwngpass"
[5618] Connected to WiFi
[5619] Connecting to mqtt.mydevices.com:1883
AT+CIPSTART=1,"TCP","mqtt.mydevices.com",1883
[15636] Network connect failed
AT+CIPSTART=1,"TCP","mqtt.mydevices.com",1883
AT+CIPSEND=1,40
MQIsdp
9c6b2/things/743674368676328742somenumbersAT+CIPSEND=1,16
e7f5ba423/cmd/+
AT+CIPSEND=1,40
AT+CIPSEND=1,40
AT+CIPSEND=1,40
AT+CIPSEND=1,40
1i Zv1/743674368676328742somenumbersAT+CIPSEND=1,40
6b2/things/743674368676328742somenumbersAT+CIPSEND=1,27
f5ba423/data/4temp,c=28.125sensor = 0     output = 0.000
Power =0.000
AT+CIPSEND=1,40
1g
```

Comment: I removed your passwords from the question. Is it an ESP8266 shield (if yes add  link to product) or a normal esp8266 module

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't notice the privacy issue. I use the ESP8266 ESP-01 module which connected to Arduino UNO. This is a module that comes from a Taobao bundle. If you still not clear I can give you the link

Comment: Yes please give a link or post a photo of your combination Thanks

Comment: https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a220m.1000858.1000725.1.6fa53063NyqKph&id=523957302031&skuId=3990354335690&user_id=1829684076&cat_id=2&is_b=1&rn=02e0fa0be8fd3436466a4654b6e6f4d2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Comment: What kind of private information I have posted?

Answer (score 1):

If your module is getting warm its probably a hardwareissue.I guess you use 5V for the esp module which is bad as it only needs 3.3V. It might survive 5V for a short time(moment) but don't stretch your luck. So you have to convert 5V ro 3.3V level shifter. You **can not** use the Arduino 3.3V output pin because it can not provide the power needed by the ESP (up to 250mA) vs. max 50mA on the Arduino (UNO) 3.3V pin.

[image]

The schematic shortly explained:

- The ESP's VCC pin is powered by the 3.3V output pin of the voltage regulator (AMS1117 in the grphic).
- The 10uF capacitor is connected to the output pins to stabilize the regulator.
- The CH_PD pin must also be connected to 3.3V.
- The GND pin is obviously connected to ground.
- The ESP's TXD pin can be connected directly to the RX pin of Arduino (emulated on pin 6).
- The ESP's RXD pin is connected to the TX pin of Arduino (emulated on pin 7) through the level shifter.

The last two can be changed depending if you use hardware or software serial 
**EDIT**
As you use rtc it makes no sense to update the time every loop this will crash your connection. Either do it every x hours and make sure with if/else that nochyenne loop() is running. It makes no sense to sync time every x millis() the syncing of time every hourisenough foryour scenario, I would go for once a day

Comment: Actually I just use the 3.3V port in the Arduino. When I only write 2 component's code to communicate with the Cayenne server, it works fine(Power sensor and receive slider data in Cayenne). However, it starts to heat up when I add more component

Comment: Add more component Software or hardware? If its hardware watch forcurrent draw if it is softwere your ESP has probably a defect -it uses around 80mA and gets quite warm in AP mode (but within specs) .So again have you connected as in my graphic if not you will continue to stagger in the dark

Comment: I will try to buy those components. Really thanks for your detail solution.

Comment: Also I want to ask is it available to use other 3.3V voltage regulator but not AMS1117? Since I cannot find it in local stores.

Comment: Yes the type of voltage regulator can be of any similar type, you could also use a level shifter module for that

Comment: I have connected the circuit with the above diagram. The Arduino board is successfully connected to the Cayenne IoT server without the myRTC.updateTime();. However, once I add this line of codde it will disconnect again. What is the reason?

Comment: Also, I have connected the real-time clock with CLK = pin 6, DATA = pin 7, RST = pin 8

Comment: See my edit above and please markthe original question as solver